# Userclass isn't Processing the value for username and password for comparing when value taken from login class

Tags: java, javafx

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;

public class Login extends Application 
{
static Stage classStage = new Stage();
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{

Text t = new Text("Welcome To Our Library");
t.setFont(Font.font("Arial Black", 24.0));

Label l1 = new Label("User Name: ");
l1.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 16));
l1.setPadding(new Insets(10));
TextField t1 = new TextField();
t1.setPromptText("Your Username");
t1.selectAll();
t1.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,50));

Label l2 = new Label("Password: ");
l2.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 16));
l2.setPadding(new Insets(10));
TextField t2 = new TextField();
t2.setPromptText("Your Username");

t2.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,50));

Button b1 = new Button("Register");
b1.setPadding(new Insets(10,40,10,40));
b1.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 14px; ");
Button b2 = new Button("Login");
b2.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 14px; ");
b2.setPadding(new Insets(10,50,10,50));

b1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
Register r = new Register();
r.start(Register.classStage);
primaryStage.hide();
}
);

User u = new User();
String user = u.getusername();
String pass = u.getconfirm_password();


b2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
if(t1.getText().equals(user) && t2.getText().equals(pass))
{
Welcome r = new Welcome();
r.start(Welcome.classStage);
primaryStage.hide();
}
}
}
);



VBox root = new VBox();
HBox h = new HBox();

HBox h1 = new HBox();
HBox h2 = new HBox();
HBox h3 = new HBox();
h3.setSpacing(35.0);    

h.setPadding(new Insets(100,100,10,100));
h1.setPadding(new Insets(50,100,10,100));
h2.setPadding(new Insets(20,100,10,110));
h3.setPadding(new Insets(20,80,10,80));



h.getChildren().addAll(t);
h1.getChildren().addAll(l1,t1);
h2.getChildren().addAll(l2,t2);
h3.getChildren().addAll(b1,b2);

h.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
h1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
h2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
h3.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


root.getChildren().addAll(h,h1,h2,h3);


Scene s = new Scene(root,700,600);
primaryStage.setTitle("Library Mangement System");
primaryStage.setScene(s);
primaryStage.show();
Login.classStage = primaryStage ;


}


}  
}
```

Registration class for creating registration form.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;

public class Register extends Application{
static Stage classStage = new Stage();
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
Text t = new Text("Complete the form below to create your new Library  account");
t.setFont(Font.font("Arial Black", 16));

Label l1 = new Label("First Name: ");
l1.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 16));
l1.setPadding(new Insets(10));
TextField t1 = new TextField();
t1.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,50));

Label l2 = new Label("Last Name: ");
l2.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 16));
l2.setPadding(new Insets(10));
TextField t2 = new TextField();
t2.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,50));

Label l3 = new Label("User Name: ");
l3.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 16));
l3.setPadding(new Insets(10));
TextField t3 = new TextField();
t3.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,50));

Label l4 = new Label("Password: ");
l4.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 16));
l4.setPadding(new Insets(10));
TextField t4 = new TextField();
t4.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,50));

Label l5 = new Label("Confirm Password: ");
l5.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 16));
l5.setPadding(new Insets(10));
TextField t5 = new TextField();
t5.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,50));

Label l6 = new Label("Contact Number: ");
l6.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 16));
l6.setPadding(new Insets(10));
TextField t6 = new TextField();
t6.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,50));

Label l7 = new Label("Email: ");
l7.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 16));
l7.setPadding(new Insets(10));
TextField t7 = new TextField();
t7.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,50));

Label l8 = new Label("Sex: ");
l8.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 16));
l8.setPadding(new Insets(10));
final ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton("Male");
rb1.setToggleGroup(group);
rb1.setSelected(true);

RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton("Female");
rb2.setToggleGroup(group);
rb1.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,30));
rb2.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,30));

Button b1 = new Button("Cancel");
b1.setPadding(new Insets(10,40,10,40));
b1.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 14));
Button b2 = new Button("Confirm");
b2.setPadding(new Insets(10,40,10,40));
b2.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 14));

b1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
Login l = new Login();
l.start(Login.classStage);
primaryStage.hide();
}
}
)
;

b2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
/*if(t4.getText()!=t5.getText()){
alert.setTitle("Warning Dialog");
alert.setHeaderText("Password doesn't match!");
alert.setContentText("Try again with different password.");
alert.showAndWait();
}*/ 
User u = new User();

Login l = new Login();
l.start(Login.classStage);
primaryStage.hide();

}
}
);

VBox root = new VBox();
HBox h = new HBox();
HBox h1 = new HBox();
HBox h2 = new HBox();
HBox h3 = new HBox();
HBox h4 = new HBox();
HBox h5 = new HBox();
HBox h6 = new HBox();
HBox h7 = new HBox();
HBox h8 = new HBox();
HBox h9 = new HBox();
h9.setSpacing(30.0);

h.setPadding(new Insets(30,100,10,100));
h1.setPadding(new Insets(30,100,10,100));
h2.setPadding(new Insets(10,100,10,100));
h3.setPadding(new Insets(10,100,10,100));
h4.setPadding(new Insets(10,100,10,110));
h5.setPadding(new Insets(10,100,10,50));
h6.setPadding(new Insets(10,100,10,65));
h7.setPadding(new Insets(10,100,10,140));
h8.setPadding(new Insets(10,100,10,140));
h9.setPadding(new Insets(20,80,10,80));
h9.setSpacing(25.0);

h.getChildren().addAll(t);
h1.getChildren().addAll(l1,t1);
h2.getChildren().addAll(l2,t2);
h3.getChildren().addAll(l3,t3);
h4.getChildren().addAll(l4,t4);
h5.getChildren().addAll(l5,t5);
h6.getChildren().addAll(l6,t6);
h7.getChildren().addAll(l7,t7);
h8.getChildren().addAll(l8,rb1,rb2);
h9.getChildren().addAll(b1,b2);

h.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
h1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
h2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
h3.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
h4.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
h5.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
h6.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
h7.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
h8.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
h9.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

root.getChildren().addAll(h,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,h9);
Scene s = new Scene(root,700,650);
primaryStage.setScene(s);
primaryStage.setTitle("Registration");
primaryStage.show();

}



}
```

Now there needs a user class which will have all the value of the register form.

```
class User{

private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String username;
private String password;
private String confirm_password;
private String contactno;
private String email;

public User()
{   

}

public User(String firstname,String lastname,String username,String      password,String confirm_password,String contactno,String email)
{

this.setfirstname(firstname);
this.setlastname(lastname);
this.setusername(username);
this.setpassword(password);
this.setconfirm_password(confirm_password);
this.setcontactno(contactno);
this.setemail(email);

}

public void setusername(String username)
{
    this.username=username;
}

public void setpassword(String password)
{
this.password=password;
}

public void setconfirm_password(String confirm_password)
{
this.confirm_password=confirm_password;
}

public void setfirstname(String firstname)
{
this.firstname=firstname;
}

public void setlastname(String lastname)
{
this.lastname=lastname;
}

public void setcontactno(String contactno)
{
this.contactno=contactno;
}

public void setemail(String email)
{
this.email=email;
}



public String getusername()
{
return this.username;
}

public String getpassword()
{
    return this.password;
}

public String getconfirm_password()
{
    return this.confirm_password;
}

public String getfirstname()
{
    return this.firstname;
}

public String getlastname()
{
    return this.lastname;
}

public String getcontactno()
{
    return this.contactno;
}

public String getemail()
{
    return this.email;
}


}
```

This program needs to work like this.A register form will first appear.After user gives the details.All the info like firstname,lastname,password,email,sex etc all the details will be transferred to the user class.so when that user login to the system It will check the value of username and password from user class and compare them.When mismatch occurs it will show errors

Comment: do you really expect people to debug this unformatted wall of text?  Just show the relevant portion. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: " all the details will be transferred to the user class" - that is wrong. The details are transfer to an instance of the user class. And every time you call `new User()` you get a new instance with new details